What is the difference between Modern Valence Bond Theory and Valence Bond Theory
I found out that modernized VBT calculates its wavefunction by basically taking average of ground, non-ground covalent state and ionic states. So hydrogen main contributor is ground covalent state. General normal VBT with wavefunction measured by Heilter and London proved to be incomplete.
I am wondering whether what I said about wavefunction in this modernized valence bond theory which calculates wavefunction with Quantum chemistry is correct and how this method differentiates from normal Heilter and London method in describing bonding. This modernized VBT also includes Coulson-Fischer method which might provide insight into how it differentiates from Valence Bond Theory
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_valence_bond_theory

Could you cite the article you are referring to?
